# What is the purpose of the c flag in the "conda install -c package" command

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I'm learning to set up Python environments using Conda, and I noticed that on the Anaconda Cloud website they recommend installing packages using the syntax:

```
conda install -c package
```

However, on the conda documentation they use the same command without the `c` flag.

Could anyone explain to me what is the purpose of the `c` flag, and when should it be used?

Answer (score 48):

`-c` stands for `--channel`.
It's used to specify a [channel](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html#Channel%20Customization) where to search for your package, the channel is often named **owner**.

The generic command is: `conda install -c CHANNEL_NAME PACKAGE_NAME`

For example, let's say you want to download pytorch. You can search on [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=pytorch). You'll see that pytorch (the pacakge) is owned by pytorch.

[image]

Then, you'll just have to do a:

`conda install -c pytorch pytorch`

Answer (score 18):

Copied from CLI after running `conda install -h`:

> -c CHANNEL, --channel CHANNEL
>
> Additional channel to search for packages. These are
>                           URLs searched in the order they are given (including
>                           file:// for local directories). Then, the defaults or
>                           channels from .condarc are searched (unless
>                           --override-channels is given). You can use 'defaults'
>                           to get the default packages for conda, and 'system' to
>                           get the system packages, which also takes .condarc
>                           into account. You can also use any name and the
>                           .condarc channel_alias value will be prepended. The
>                           default channel_alias is http://conda.anaconda.org/.

Channels are locations where Navigator and conda look for packages. ([source](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/manage-channels/)) A package with the same name may exist on multiple channels. If you wish to install from other than the default channel, than one way of specifying which channel to use, is to use the `conda install -c channel_name package_name` syntax.
Also read [this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages) for a description of install process using channels.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea I could use the -h flag on every conda command