# import torch: How to fix OSError WinError 126, error loading fbgemm.dll or dependencies

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, python-import, oserror

I installed the modules below:

```
conda install pytorch==2.2.0 torchvision==0.17.0 torchaudio==2.2.0 -c pytorch
```

Then installed numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, sickit-learn, pyedflib in this environment. Yet upon `import` it seems some files are missing:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 import torch
      2 from torch import nn
      3 import numpy as np

File d:\anaconda3\envs\RN\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py:141
    139                 err = ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    140                 err.strerror += f' Error loading "{dll}" or one of its dependencies.'
--> 141                 raise err
    143     kernel32.SetErrorMode(prev_error_mode)
    146 def _preload_cuda_deps(lib_folder, lib_name):

OSError: [WinError 126] can't find this module. Error loading "d:\anaconda3\envs\RN\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
```

I reinstalled torch, but I can't solve it.
And I even checked the file 'fbgemm.dll', it is there.

Comment: oh I solve this problem. thank you for your help. When I check a new environment there has differences about whether files are. So I remove some files that are not in new environment, then it can work.

Comment: you manually removed files from the base environment to keep working in it? If I got it right, better use the new env instead. Otherwise it might create problems later?

Comment: because this looks like a problem others might have i went ahead and edited your post. It's be great if you would take the time to review my edit, especially you install line

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, somehow, another file is missing (*one of its dependencies*). Starting from a **new environment** could remove unnecessary constraints. Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77859957/12846804), with all requirements at once, not one part then add the other modules:

```
conda create -n env_torch pytorch=2.2.0 torchvision=0.17.0 torchaudio=2.2.0 numpy pandas matplotlib seaborn scikit-learn pyedflib
activate env_torch
```

The conda [cheat sheet](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) is your best friend. Other things I looked up:

- similar issue with pip, not conda: [While importing torch WinError 126 The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65931555/12846804),
- [What is the purpose of the c flag in the "conda install" command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54845807/12846804)